# How to up date an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays of objects. The first array has 12 entries with 2 properites date and cost(all are zero). The other array only has 5 entries with the same 2 properties date and cost(has values).

How do I update array 1 based on the array 2 matching the date and updating the cost?

```
array1 = [
    {
        date: '2020-01',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-02',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-03',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-04',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-05',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-06',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-07',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-08',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-09',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-10',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-11',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-12',
        cost: 0
    }
];


array2 = [
    {
        date: '2020-01',
        cost: 10
    },
    {
        date: '2020-02',
        cost: 5
    },
    {
        date: '2020-05',
        cost: 20
    },
    {
        date: '2020-06',
        cost: 65
    },
    {
        date: '2020-07',
        cost: 11
    }
];
```

final array:

```
finaArray = [
    {
        date: '2020-01',
        cost: 10
    },
    {
        date: '2020-02',
        cost: 5
    },
    {
        date: '2020-03',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-04',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-05',
        cost: 20
    },
    {
        date: '2020-06',
        cost: 65
    },
    {
        date: '2020-07',
        cost: 11
    },
    {
        date: '2020-08',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-09',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-10',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-11',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-12',
        cost: 0
    }
];
```

What ive done so far:

```
const test = array1.map((e1, i1) => {
    array2.map((e2, i2) => {
        if (e1.date === e2.date) {
            
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @blex tried to reopen it and submit the change in question but wasnt letting me. Just wanted to submit it before the ened of the weekend otherwise I wouldnt get round to it again until next weekend. But thanks for your help

Comment: No problem, I was just letting you know that if you waited 2 more minutes, 1 more person would have voted to reopen it, and you would have had answers coming in ;)

Comment: Thanks blex new to this and how it works. Now I know ill be more patient next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer only loops over each instance once in each array, by turning the array2 into an object with the date as key, using `Object.assign()`, that then is compared to the array1, through `map()`, by looking up the date.

```js
function turnIntoObj(arr) {
  return Object.assign(...arr.map(item => ({ [item.date]: item.cost })));
}

function joinArr(originalArr, toBeAddedArr) {
  let toBeAddedObj = turnIntoObj(toBeAddedArr);

  return originalArr.map((item) => {
    if (toBeAddedObj[item.date]) { 
      item.cost += toBeAddedObj[item.date];
    }
    return item;
  });
}


array1 = [
    {
        date: '2020-01',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-02',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-03',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-04',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-05',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-06',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-07',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-08',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-09',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-10',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-11',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-12',
        cost: 0
    }
];


array2 = [
    {
        date: '2020-01',
        cost: 10
    },
    {
        date: '2020-02',
        cost: 5
    },
    {
        date: '2020-05',
        cost: 20
    },
    {
        date: '2020-06',
        cost: 65
    },
    {
        date: '2020-07',
        cost: 11
    }
];

let updatedArr = joinArr(array1, array2);
console.log(updatedArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the elements with the same date, and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to calculate the sum of their costs:

```js
const array1 = [{date:"2020-01",cost:0},{date:"2020-02",cost:0},{date:"2020-03",cost:0},{date:"2020-04",cost:0},{date:"2020-05",cost:0},{date:"2020-06",cost:0},{date:"2020-07",cost:0},{date:"2020-08",cost:0},{date:"2020-09",cost:0},{date:"2020-10",cost:0},{date:"2020-11",cost:0},{date:"2020-12",cost:0}],
      array2 = [{date:"2020-01",cost:10},{date:"2020-02",cost:5},{date:"2020-05",cost:20},{date:"2020-06",cost:65},{date:"2020-07",cost:11}];

const test = array1.map((a) => {
  const toMerge = array2.filter(b => a.date === b.date);
  
  return {
    ...a,
    cost: [a].concat(toMerge).reduce((sum, {cost}) => sum + cost, 0)
  };
});

console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Blex answer works fine, below another basic solution : (tested)

```
var finalArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length - 1; i++) {
  finalArray.push(array1[i]);
  for (var j = 0 ; j < array2.length - 1; j++) {
      if (array1[i].date == array2[j].date) {
          finalArray[i].cost = array2[j].cost + array1[i].cost;
          break;
      }
  }
}
console.log(finalArray);
```

attached a screen shot of final array values

[Final Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRoKY.png)

Answer (score 0):

to update array1 (no new array creation )

```js
const array1 = [{date:"2020-01",cost:0},{date:"2020-02",cost:0},{date:"2020-03",cost:0},{date:"2020-04",cost:0},{date:"2020-05",cost:0},{date:"2020-06",cost:0},{date:"2020-07",cost:0},{date:"2020-08",cost:0},{date:"2020-09",cost:0},{date:"2020-10",cost:0},{date:"2020-11",cost:0},{date:"2020-12",cost:0}],
      array2 = [{date:"2020-01",cost:10},{date:"2020-02",cost:5},{date:"2020-05",cost:20},{date:"2020-06",cost:65},{date:"2020-07",cost:11}];

array2.forEach(a2=>
  {
  let a1 = array1.find(x=>x.date===a2.date)
  if(a1) a1.cost = a2.cost 
  })
array1.forEach( (a1,i) => console.log(`array1[${i}] -> ${JSON.stringify(a1)}`))
```

If array1 and array2 are in the same order, and each array2 element exist in array1 :

```js
const array1 = [{date:"2020-01",cost:0},{date:"2020-02",cost:0},{date:"2020-03",cost:0},{date:"2020-04",cost:0},{date:"2020-05",cost:0},{date:"2020-06",cost:0},{date:"2020-07",cost:0},{date:"2020-08",cost:0},{date:"2020-09",cost:0},{date:"2020-10",cost:0},{date:"2020-11",cost:0},{date:"2020-12",cost:0}],
      array2 = [{date:"2020-01",cost:10},{date:"2020-02",cost:5},{date:"2020-05",cost:20},{date:"2020-06",cost:65},{date:"2020-07",cost:11}];

let a2 = array2.shift()
for(a1 of array1)
  {
  if (a2.date===a1.date)
    {
    a1.cost = a2.cost
    a2      = array2.shift()
    }
  if (!a2) break // stop loop update
  }

// proof...
array1.forEach( (a1,i) => console.log(`${i}-> ${JSON.stringify(a1)}`))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce to do that,

```js
array1 = [
    {
        date: '2020-01',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-02',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-03',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-04',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-05',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-06',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-07',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-08',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-09',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-10',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-11',
        cost: 0
    },
    {
        date: '2020-12',
        cost: 0
    }
];


array2 = [
    {
        date: '2020-01',
        cost: 10
    },
    {
        date: '2020-02',
        cost: 5
    },
    {
        date: '2020-05',
        cost: 20
    },
    {
        date: '2020-06',
        cost: 65
    },
    {
        date: '2020-07',
        cost: 11
    }
];

const ret = array1.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const index = array2.findIndex(item => item.date === curr.date);
    if(index > -1){
         curr.cost = array2[index].cost;
    }
    acc.push(curr);
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(ret);
```